# Stream upload image from bundle using swift3 gets an error

Tags: ios, swift3, upload, stream, alamofire

I have configured an input stream to transfer an image to http server, but I am facing an error: `Assertion failed: (CFReadStreamGetStatus(_stream.get()) == kCFStreamStatusNotOpen), function bodyStartProvidingData_block_invoke, file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/CFNetwork/CFNetwork-811.4.18/HTTP/Core/IO/HTTPTransaction.cpp, line 2122.` And the path is not allowed to visit.

How can I solve the problem?

I have done the following configurations, you can get the error message if you follow the steps below:

1.Copy and paste the code below to your project, install Alamofire
 2. Drag and drop an image named `shot.png`(you can take an screenshot and rename it to 'shot.png') to your project.
 3. Run Xcode, and touch the screen after it starts, and gets the error message in the console!

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var customInputStream:InputStream?

let sourceFileName = "shot.png"
let destinationUrlString = "http://httpbin.org/stream/:11"


///buffer size
let bufferSize = 1048576 //1024 * 1024

let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "shot.png", ofType: nil)!

//binary data of the file
var fileData = NSData()

//size of the data
var dataLength = 0
var fileSize:Int64 = 0

///inputstream counter
var readedBytes = 0
var sendedByteIndex = 0


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let image = UIImage(named: path)!
    fileData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)! as NSData
    dataLength = fileData.length
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    setUpInStreamForFile(path: path)

    let url = URL(string: destinationUrlString)

    let request = URLRequest(url: url!, cachePolicy: URLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData, timeoutInterval: 30)

    Alamofire.upload(customInputStream!, with: request).response { (response) in
        print("response:\(response)")

    }
}
}


 extension ViewController:StreamDelegate{

// MARK: - InputStream
func setUpInStreamForFile(path:String) -> () {
    customInputStream = InputStream(fileAtPath: path)
    customInputStream?.delegate = self
    customInputStream?.schedule(in: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)
    customInputStream?.open()
}

func stream(_ aStream: Stream, handle eventCode: Stream.Event) {
    print("eventCode:\(eventCode)")

    if aStream is InputStream {
        switch eventCode {
        // has data to read
        case Stream.Event.openCompleted, Stream.Event.hasBytesAvailable:

            readedBytes += sendedByteIndex

            var length = (dataLength - readedBytes) >= bufferSize ? bufferSize : (dataLength - readedBytes)
            var buffer = [UInt8](repeatElement(0, count: length))
            fileData.getBytes(&buffer, range: NSRange(location: readedBytes, length: bufferSize))
            length = (aStream as! InputStream).read(&buffer, maxLength: bufferSize)

            sendedByteIndex = length

        //read to the end of the stream
        case Stream.Event.endEncountered:
            aStream.close()
            aStream.remove(from: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)
            //aStream = nil

        case Stream.Event.errorOccurred:
            print("error occurs!")

        default:
            break
        }
    }
}  
}
```

Comment: you can use this for uploading image using Alamofire.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47151184/swift-http-load-failed-error-code-1005-4-4-while-uploading-image-throu/47151590#47151590
as you are using input stream for passing an image to http server this might reduce your effort.

Comment: I can't even reproduce this with the code you provided, I get a range exception related to the buffer shenanigans. I did notice in your example you're not using https, but didn't mention anything about ATS exceptions. Maybe that's it? If not, please fix your buffer logic, I don't have the time to do so atm. :)

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm facing the same problem